# No indents on blank lines

Tags: tabs, resharper, visual-studio-2019

When I write code, and press Enter, then I insert a new blank line, with normal indents, as it should be.

[image: Normal]

However, if I click the cursor to another location, and then click back to this line, it will be placed at the beginning of the line.

[image: After]

How to fix it?

I tried to fix it in the ReSharper settings, but did not find it.

Comment: Have you tried clicking "End" on your keyboard?

Comment: When curson at the beginning oh the line? Yes, but nothing happened

Comment: This happens to me when I have the XAML Formatter addon. Do you have any addon activate?

Comment: If it is not shipped immediately with Visual Studio 2019 - then no.

Comment: For me, the functionality works as such - pressing enter after the line you are typing on leaves the cursor at the same indentation level (the new line is blank until you type something and it will pad it with spaces). If you do not type anything and move the cursor away from that line and then back again it should set the cursor to either the home column or the last indented column if you mouse click beyond that column. You could always enable virtual space then you can place your cursor where ever you want.

Comment: If you realize that you need to switch something, everything would work for me the same way as yours - write the answer - I will accept it. Virtual space does not suit me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing enter after the line you are typing on leaves the cursor at the same indentation level (the new line is blank until you type something and then it will pad it with spaces). If you do not type anything and move the cursor away from that line and then back again it should set the cursor to either the home column or the last indented column if you mouse click beyond that column (further to the right). This only works with mouse clicking, using the cursor keys will only set you to the home position on the new line.

You could always enable virtual space then you can place your cursor where ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Tab, if you use space, it stays as it should be but it is not a good practice.

Comment: I change `Intend Style` to Spaces, but it's don't help.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019